# Div con 100% de altura sin barra de scroll

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo un `div` que tiene un vídeo como fondo , sin embargo no se ajusta 100% al *height* sino que, se pasa siempre un poquito y aparece esa barra de scroll vertical. ¿Saben como hacer que esto no ocurra y se adapte realmente al 100% del *height*? ya sea con [css](/questions/tagged/css) o alguna clase de [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap).

```
<div class="index-fluid">
  <video id="video-home" autoplay="autoplay" poster="img/index-video-poster.png" loop>
    <source src="media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
</div>


#video-home {  
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height:100%;

}
.index-fluid{
    padding :0px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el tamaño de tu imagen? Probablemente tengas que modificar las dimensiones de esta para que no haga el overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si ocurre un desbordamiento se debe a que existe un border o padding que hace que ocupe más allá de sus dimensiones. Recuerda que todo elemento tiene 4 cajas: caja de margen, caja de borde, caja de relleno y caja de contenido. Esas cuatro cajas conforman las dimensiones de todo elemento.

La etiqueta `video` es un elemento `inline` y, como se tiene conocimiento, estos elementos agregan una especie de espacio en blanco al rededor de ellos, causando que sus dimensiones iniciales se vean  afectadas.

La solución (hay varias) es simple: hacer el video un elemento de bloque:

```css
/*
 * Reseteado CSS básico. Todo navegador
 * agrega por defecto estilos a las etiquetas,
 * por lo que es conveniente "normalizarlas".
 * Además, es recomendado usar el modelo de
 * caja border-box en lugar de content-box.
 */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.video {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.video video {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="video">
  <video controls autoplay>
    <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/odxyj57wwvz0mib/deadpool2-trailer.mp4?dl=0" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
</section>
```

He usado `object-fit` la cual hace que ciertas etiquetas como `video` desechen el aspect ratio por defecto y se adapte a las dimensiones. Si quieres hacer un fullscreen completo, te puede servir la [API Fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) que tiene un soporte bastante decente. Por otro lado, el [soporte para `object-fit`](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) es también bueno, excepto por IE y Edge (supongo este último lo implementará pronto).

Comment: De nada. Buenas noticias: el soporte para `object-fit` en Edge está en desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar el scroll se usa la opcion CSS overflow, usa overflow:hidden; y no saldrá la barra, pero si el contenido es mayor se cortará.
Si usando height 100% se pasa un poquito, puede deberse a que hay algún padding o borde, prueba a quitarlo con padding:0px; y border-width: 0px; Tambien podria passar que el objeto padre tenga algún margin, si es el caso calcula el tamaño del div respecto al padre o usa un margin:0px;

Comment: si, yo creo que es por las clases de bootstrap, con el overflow hidden me arreglló el problema muchas gracias, sin embargo me surge una pequeña duda más, si hago pequeña la ventana del navegador el video respeta sus proporciones y no ocupa el 100% de la ventana , ¿esto se puede cambiar para que siempre ocupe el 100%? aunque suis proporciones no se mantengan?.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Usando height 100%, usa el 100% del padre, si el tamaño del padre fuera fijo, no varia según el tamaño de la ventana.
Pero creo que en tu caso es un tema de proporciones, si le dices que el ancho sea 100%, el lo pone al 100% aunque no quepa de alto, por eso se corta, si quieres que el video se haga mas pequeño para que quepa puedes recalcular su tamaño dentro el evento onresize.
Ahora no sabría decirte una solución CSS

Answer (score -1):

Para quitar el scroll vertical pon este código en tu fichero `style.css` No necesitarás JavaScript. Pruébenlo:

```
html,body{
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    color:black; 
    font-family:'Opens Sans',helvetica;
    height:100%; 
    width:101%; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Hola Facundo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. He visto que has copiado la misma respuesta en 2 preguntas (ésta y la de [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/120277/250)). Que la misma respuesta sin cambio alguno sirva para más de una pregunta es una señal de que algo no va bien: o bien las preguntas son duplicadas, o bien la respuesta no responde realmente a una de las preguntas. Parecería que es lo segundo, porque OP pregunta por como ajustar el tamaño de un video y tu respuesta se limita a cambiar los estilos del html/body (lo que harán que parte del vídeo quede oculto)

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [answer] y que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y así ganar tu primera medalla)