# Ocultar barra de scroll sin deshabilitarlo

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css3

Quisiera encontrar la manera de ocultar la *barra de scroll* en el navegador.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

Pero seteando `overflow:hidden` en el `body`, lo que sucede es que aparte de desaparecer, queda inhabilitada la funcionalidad de *Scroll* y necesito que siga funcionando.

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código con lo que hayas intentado. Tal y como está redactada la pregunta ahora, es demasiado amplia.

Answer (score 5):

Lo ideal seria poner en el archivo CSS

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
```

Esto permite usar la rueda del ratón para hacer scroll y no deshabilita el scroll propiamente dicho.

Lo han comentado en el siguiente post [¿Como ocultar el scrollbar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56179/como-ocultar-el-scrollbar/56962)

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que llego a entender de [ESTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page/23771140#23771140) respuesta en SO, utilizando un contenedor con la propiedad overflow hidden y jugando con margin y padding de un div interno, se puede llegar a ocultar la barra de scroll.

Hasta hay un [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H47fp/) dónde funciona.

La estructura que utiliza para obtener el efecto es la siguiente:

**HTML**

```
<div class="hide-scroll">
    <div class="viewport">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.viewport {
    overflow: auto;

    /* Make sure the inner div is not larger than the container
     * so that we have room to scroll.
     */
    max-height: 100%;

    /* Pick an arbitrary margin/padding that should be bigger
     * than the max width of all the scroll bars across
     * the devices you are targeting.
     * padding = -margin
     */
    margin-right: -100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Slds!

Answer (score 1):

Hola Tengo esta definición css para ocultar las barras scroll pero si colocas el mouse sobre el borde estas aparecen y puedes usarlas tranquilamente. Si sacas el mouse del borde, la barra vuelve a desaparecer. También puedes darle el color que quieras.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 9px; height: 9px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button { width: 0px; height: 0px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: transparent; border: 0px none #fff; border-radius: 10px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { background: #3d6077;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active { background: #8dd0d8;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: transparent;border: 0px solid #aaa; border-radius: 5px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover { background: #e4e4e4;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active { background: #d2d2d2;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background: transparent;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quitar el scroll vertical pon este código en tu fichero `style.css` No necesitarás JavaScript. Pruébenlo:

```
html,body{
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    color:black; 
    font-family:'Opens Sans',helvetica;
    height:100%; 
    width:101%; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso no me funcionaron las respuestas anteriores. Quizá se deba a que mi input era "number". Esto fue lo que me funcionó:

```
::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente código css, se logra ocultar la barra del scroll, y sigue funcionando el scroll.

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: y que hace esto?

Comment: Oculta la barra del scroll, pero sigue funcionando el scroll.

Comment: pues agrega una explicación a tu código, por que así no parece una respuesta

Comment: Gracias, tienes razón.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar el color de la scrollbar para que sea transparente

```css
html,body {
  scrollbar-color:  transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso me funcionó el siguiente código css.

```
*{
   scrollbar-width: none;
 }
```

Utiliza la propiedad [scrollbar-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) a las que se le puede dar el valor *'auto', 'thin' o 'none'*, esta ultima para remover el scroll sin eliminar la capacidad de desplazarse por otros mecanismos (como con una pantalla tactil).

Hay que aclarar que esta propiedad tiene muy poca compatibilidad con la mayoría de navegadores, sobre todo si se coloca tal y como esta, se puede extender la compatibilidad con el prefijo *'webkit'*:

```
* {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -webkit-scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Tabla de compatibilidad [aqui](https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-scrollbar-width).